# Regex: Words with spaces into string array

Tags: php, regex, arrays, string

I have strings that I'm printing as:

```
$string = "winter coats gloves hats blankets sleeping bags tarps milk magnesia shoes boots art";
```

That I need to regex into a string array, like:

```
$newString = array ('winter','coats','gloves','hats','blankets','sleeping','bags','tarps','milk','magnesia','shoes','boots','art');
```

The challenge is, how to add only `'` on each end, while `','` to replace the spaces...

So far I have this, which doesn't work...

```
$string = str.replace(/\s+/g, '','',$string);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I don't misunderstand you, simply:

```
$array = explode(' ', $string);
```

This will create a string array out of your string.

[explode() in PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

What you have tried does not work because it is Javascript. If you clarify a bit what you're trying to achieve exactly, and how Javascript comes into the picture, we could help further.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function instead.

```
$array = explode (' ', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

any reason you can't use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) for this? it would seem to do exactly what you want.